# Permanent aliases priority

Tags: 14.04, alias

So I've opened a wonderful world of aliases and immediately  created a pack of aliases for using with Git and other tools. However it appears that some of the aliases I've declared were already reserved for some other programs, some of them are not even installed yet.

For instance `go` is already reserved for the Go language, I presume. And even though I've assigned `go` to another task, it still returns:

```
The program 'go' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gccgo-go
```

Can I override it manually? And even, is it a good idea to override these commands, maybe I should better come up with something that is not reserved by the OS?

`.bash_aliases` file:

```
alias gs='git status '
alias gl='git log '
alias glf='git log --graph --oneline --all --decorate'
alias ga='git add '
alias gb='git branch '
alias gc='git commit'
alias gd='git diff'
alias go='git checkout '
```

Terminal:

```
~ > alias gs
alias gs='git status '
~ > alias gl
alias gl='git log '
~ > alias go
bash: alias: go: not found
***
~ > go
The program 'go' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gccgo-go
```

Maybe this is some sort of a bug and I should reboot the OS?

Comment: How did you set the alias?

Comment: As per recommendations found here on AskUbuntu, I've edited  `.bash_aliases` file.

Comment: Run `alias go` ..what do you get ?

Comment: Run `alias go='git checkout '` in the terminal and then check `alias go` ..what do you get ? also you don't need `alias` in front of all the alias lines in `~/.bash_aliases`

Comment: After I ran `alias go='git checkout '` in the terminal it worked, I get Git related message returned. That's amazing, I hope the changes will be persistent.

Comment: @curious_gudleif to tag someone please use `@name` format just like i did now otherwise that person won't be notified....now, this is not persistent..this only applies for the current session....now run `unalias go`, then `source ~/.bash_aliases`, then `alias go` ..what gives ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can override it. Well if you don't need the other command, then it is your system, so of course it is totally ok to do it. You can set the alias in

`nano ~/.profile`

`nano ~/.bashrc`

`nano ~/.bash_profile`

Most shells using ~/.profile.

Comment: What about `.bash_aliases`? I've declared aliases there, does this file has less priority than those you've mentioned?

Comment: I am not sure about it. In generally usage alias has already a higher priority depends on the shell.